# Participle of empty verbs in ancient Hebrew

Tags: hebrew, participles, ancient

What is PIEL participle of "empty" (that is 2-wav or 2-yud) verbs in (ancient) Hebrew? Do such particles have wav or yud or only two letters of the root after mem?

It seems for me, that this topic was missing in my biblical Hebrew studybook.

Comment: Are you asking about a specific binyan? Not all binyanim have a participle in m-. In binyan kal, there is no w/y, e.g. from sh-y-r "sing", *shar*.

Comment: @TKR Sorry, I forgot to mention that I ask about PIEL participles. This was my error. I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Van der Merve, Naudé and Kroeze (*A Biblical Hebrew Reference Grammar*) say (s. 18.8) that "Instead of the Piel, Pual and Hithpael stem formations, the II waw and II yod verbs have a Polel, Polal and Hithpolel stem formation, respectively. It is clear from the names of these stem formations that the final stem consonant is repeated. The conjugation of verbs in these stem formations is otherwise regular".

So the Piel participle of קומ, for example, is given as מְקוֹמֵם.

Comment: There are, however, a few exceptional forms of such roots in *pi`el* (etc.), which show *w/y* as the second consonant: e.g. *qiyyem*. Gesenius (s. 72.7) says these are "secondary formations, probably borrowed from Aramaic".